# Unset bootstrap alerts after display

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a MVC website.

For example, to log in to my website, I use a modal with a PHP script. 
This PHP script set some bootstrap alerts (depending on results).

Then, I display alerts at the top of the view :

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])) echo $_SESSION['msg']; ?>
```

The msg variable stays always and I need to 'unset' it. 
But anywhere I put the unset, if I do that the msg variable is NEVER displayed...

I don't know how that works to display the alert just once,  for example  "Welcome back, dear user ! ".

How the alert is deleted then ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the unset like in this post? [c# TempData equivalent in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514172/c-sharp-tempdata-equivalent-in-php)

Setter sets the session variable, and getter unsets the session variable before returning? Does this maybe work for you?